# Wait for onComplete callback

Tags: android

I'm trying to return a boolean value if the barcode exists. However, the way this function is currently setup, it always return false. It doesn't wait on the onComplete callback.

I've tried using a localbroadcast, no success. Tried another callback, didn't work (or I did something wrong). Thinking about using sleep(), but it makes the code a bit smelly if you ask me.

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I also tried making the onComplete function boolean instead of void. Also didn't work.

```
public boolean barcodeExists(final String barcode) {
    DocumentReference barcodeRef = mFireStore.collection("xyz")
            .document(barcode);

    barcodeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if(document.exists()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //always return false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Test case `if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if(document.exists()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }else {
                    return false;
                }`

Comment: @NileshRathod The onComplete function is async. Tried it anyway, didn't work.

Comment: @B.Cakir look at the below answer, will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create callback listener, like below

```
public interface OnCompleteCallback{
  void onComplete(boolean success);
}
```

Modify method to pass callback

```
public void barcodeExists(final String barcode,final OnCompleteCallback callback) {
    DocumentReference barcodeRef = mFireStore.collection("xyz")
            .document(barcode);

    barcodeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                callback.onComplete(document.exists());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Final call of barcodeExists

```
barcodeExists("key", new OnCompleteCallback(){
  public void onComplete(boolean success){
     // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: @B.Cakir Awesome !! Glad to know that. Thank you !!