# Passing output of one method into another method in same thread

Tags: java, android

I have two methods in my doinBackround method of Asynch task.
1st method is use to retrieve value from Cloud Database.
2nd method in used to save value in msqlite.

My issue is when 2nd method get executed, first method wont able to produce value by the time it is required and hence null is getting passed. Kindly have a look at the code snippet.

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Param... params) {
        try {
            List<Object> objectlist = mAsyncTaskFireDB.getobjectlist(params[0]);
         // Output of this method to be passed into 2nd method.
            Object[] listarray = new Object[objectlist.size()];
            for(Integer i=0;i<objectlist.size();i++)
                {
                 listarray[i] = objectlist.get(i);
                 }
            mCat_messageDao.insertAll(listarray);
            // 2nd method : Value of 1st method should come here however 
              getting null here
```

Have checked & googled but not getting right solution. I want to know what will be the best way to handle such common scenario. Thanx in advance for your help.

EDIT

```
  Asynch Class Code below
private static class insertAsyncTaskFireDB extends AsyncTask<Chat_Message,Void, Void> {

    private Firestore_dB mAsyncTaskFireDB;
    private Chat_MessageDao mCat_messageDao;
    private OnChatMsgreadFStoredB onChatMsglistner;
    insertAsyncTaskFireDB(Firestore_dB dB,Chat_MessageDao mChat_messageDao,OnChatMsgreadFStoredB calback) {
        mAsyncTaskFireDB = dB;
        mCat_messageDao = mChat_messageDao;
        onChatMsglistner = calback;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Chat_Message... params) {

        if(params[0].groupID == null)
        {
            params[0].setGroupID(mAsyncTaskFireDB.getChatMsgforSingleGrp(params[0].tempgrpID));
             }
        else {
            try {
       mAsyncTaskFireDB.get_chat_message(params[0], new OnChatMsgreadFStoredB() {
         @Override
      public List<Chat_Message> onMsgreadCompleteFstoredB(List<Chat_Message> chat_messages) {
      Chat_Message[] msgarray = new Chat_Message[chat_messages.size()];

       for(Integer i=0;i<chat_messages.size();i++)
        {
           msgarray[i] = chat_messages.get(i);
         }

          mCat_messageDao.insertAll(msgarray);
            return null;
                     }
                 });
                                }
            catch(Error e){Log.d(TAG, "Error is Asynch Class fetcing details from Sqlite"+e);}

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I've understood you correctly I think you have to do the stuff you want to do in your second method inside the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask

Comment: and you can use this answer to pass data from doInBackground to onPostExecute https://stackoverflow.com/q/11833978/2127203

Comment: Thanx for your response...No since 2nd method writes data into Mysqlite it is to be done in doInBackground only and not onPostExecute method.

Comment: do you call the second method from doInBackground ?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: method getobjectlist is asynchronous so obviously won't work. you need to create callback listener and pass it while fetching data from cloud, once its done then save the results from callback method. For the reference look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128042/wait-for-oncomplete-callback/52128102#52128102

Comment: Hi Krishna thanx for your reply...Any guidelines or link or small code snippet will help meanwhile searching to get some clues on the line that you suggested

Comment: if you share the code of this method getobjectlist definitely can help, better to share entire class of this mAsyncTaskFireDB

Comment: @Krishna Sharma Checked the link you provided, Were do we define Interface Class? If defined as Java class outside of main class, it said cant work on Main thread...Please suggest Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the code I requested. Share the entire class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181014/discussion-between-sukesh-saxena-and-krishna-sharma).

Comment: @Krishna Sharma Updated with Asynch class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can access `get_chat_message` from main thread as it is listener based, so while saving data you just need to execute only that part in other than main thread. Try below

```
mAsyncTaskFireDB.get_chat_message(params[0], new OnChatMsgreadFStoredB() {
  @Override
  public List<Chat_Message> onMsgreadCompleteFstoredB(List<Chat_Message> chat_messages) {
      Chat_Message[] msgarray = new Chat_Message[chat_messages.size()];
      for(Integer i=0;i<chat_messages.size();i++)
      {
        msgarray[i] = chat_messages.get(i);
      }
      new DBTask(msgarray).execute();
      return null;
  }
});

class DBTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {
    Chat_Message[] msgarray;
    public DBTask(Chat_Message[] data){
      msgarray = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void ...voids) {
       mCat_messageDao.insertAll(msgarray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got error "Cannot resolve DBTask"  in  new DBTask(msgarray).execute() command.                                                                                                              Also one thing not clear if we are doing in background, why we are getting error  "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.. Also tried to pass object mCat_messageDao into save_chat_message method but got the same error. Cant we serialize both the method through serialized way? Thanx in advance for your help

Comment: DBTask is an inner class it shouldn't give any complaints. Also with short piece of code very hard to understand what are you doing inside custom classes.

Comment: It worked ultimately just changed the position to upper side of inner class. Thanx for your support. I am just trying to retrieve data from Firestore and save it in Sqlite through Asynchronous way. Do you have any better solution for deploying it with minimum of complexity? Once again thanx for all the support you have given

Comment: @SukeshSaxena Ideally you shouldn't need to save data locally as Firstore already provides offline support. Look at more [Offline support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)
This will make you wait until the task is finished.
Please note it WILL freeze your UI thread if you use it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look a [CompletableFuture](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture) API.

You can easily handle tasks that need to run asynchronously and also have them run one after the other, using the result of the previous step to the next step, with methods such as `runAsync` and `thenApplyAsync`. Using `exceptionally`, you can also run the specified task only if the previous task ended with an exception.

It's a great API and very helpful, if you are working majorly with concurrency.

Comment: thanx for suggestion but that needs API 24 and above if I am not mistaken. My minimum API is 14 so it may not work. Further just looking to transfer data from cloud to Sqlite only and nothing more complex at this time. My understanding is that callback could be right option but were to place interface class is bugging me since when put as separate class gives me a error that "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."